# Binding the LI Index to Observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have been pondering on this and cannot seem to come to a conclusion on how I might accomplish it. Basically, I am using jQuery UI and KnockOut and I have a OL that represents a prioritized group of projects. I have the jQuery sortability all working, that is the easy part.

What I am really trying to accomplish is a way, using KO and MVVM, to bind the index position in the OL to the `priority` attribute of the view model's `projects collection`. Here is what the object returned by my data context looks like

`{ priority: ko.observable(1), title: "Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet." }`

Here is a simplified version of my VM.

```
var ViewModel = function () {

            this.projects = new ko.observableArray(ctx.getItems());
  }
```

If I can avoid it I don't want to have to manage synching the priorities using an event. Of course if I have to I will, but if I can find a way to do it within the MVVM pattern, I would like to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to push the # value of the OL INTO the viewmodel or the other way around, use viewmodel's value to display it as the # on the screen?

Comment: Ultimately I would like both. I want the OL index and the value of `priority` attribute to be bound together. So that if I change one, it resorts/updates.

Comment: this seems like a very weird case you're describing, and I have a feeling you're trying to use OL for something that's not appropriate in this scenario. that element is designed to basically autoincrement for each item, but what you're trying to do is simply display a number from view model on your object. instead of using ol, you should just output priority into a <span> next to your title and have it formatted the way you want it. ol is designed for scenarios where numbering is generated automatically based on the order it appears in page, not an arbitrary value